# Add empty index when number of index is less then 7

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I have two DatePickers one for StartDate and one for EndDate. For example when the user select 5 days I get 5 indexes with the date.

Now my question is how can I fill up this list with a minimum of 7 indexes (the filled up indexes should be empty)?

```
 var startDate = StartDate;
        var endDate = EndDate;

        List<DateTime> Days = new List<DateTime>();

        for (DateTime counter = startDate; counter <= endDate; counter = counter.AddDays(1))
        {
            if (counter.DayOfWeek == counter.DayOfWeek)
            {
                Days.Add(counter);
            }
        }
```

Here is what I have so fare. In my case this are working but it looks very ugly.
I just fill up the list with DateTime.MinValue on till I have at least 7 indexes. I am sure there is a bether way, just dont know how.

```
 var startDate = StartDate;
        var endDate = EndDate;
        var standart = DateTime.MinValue;

        List<DateTime> Days = new List<DateTime>();

        for (DateTime counter = startDate; counter <= endDate; counter = counter.AddDays(1))
        {
            if (counter.DayOfWeek == counter.DayOfWeek)
            {
                Days.Add(counter);
            }
        }
        if (Days.Count < 7)
        {
            Days.Insert(Days.Count, standart);
        }
        if (Days.Count < 7)
        {
            Days.Insert(Days.Count, standart);
        }
        if (Days.Count < 7)
        {
            Days.Insert(Days.Count, standart);
        }
        if (Days.Count < 7)
        {
            Days.Insert(Days.Count, standart);
        }
        if (Days.Count < 7)
        {
            Days.Insert(Days.Count, standart);
        }
        if (Days.Count < 7)
        {
            Days.Insert(Days.Count, standart);
        }
```

Comment: `counter.DayOfWeek == counter.DayOfWeek` it does not make sens, for me overall your issue is not clear if you could clarify.

Comment: Lets say : the User select as StartDate 01.01.2020 and as EndDate 05.01.2020 the List Days will have five indexes with the Date as value. No what i want is, to fill up this list with at least 7 Indexes, but the filled up indexes should be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the number of days that you need to add to your list in order to reach 7, and then use it in a for loop to add them:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2020, 01, 01);
var endDate = new DateTime(2020, 01, 05);
var standart = DateTime.MinValue;

List<DateTime> Days = new List<DateTime>();
int RemainingDays = 6 + (int)startDate.Day - (int)endDate.Day;

for (DateTime counter = startDate; counter <= endDate; counter = counter.AddDays(1))
        Days.Add(counter);


if (RemainingDays > 0)
    for (int i = 0; i < RemainingDays; i++)
        Days.Insert(Days.Count, standart);
```

Or if you don't want to go thru another loop you can do:

```
if (RemainingDays > 0)
    Days.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(standart, RemainingDays).ToList());
```

Note:

I didn't get what is your point with this line   `counter.DayOfWeek == counter.DayOfWeek` I think that it doesn't make any sens in this context.